# How to detect when a website which uses AJAX is completely loaded?

Tags: ajax, delphi, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

For a website, which doesn't use AJAX I'm using `OnDocumentComplete` event to know when the page loading is complete.

My question is, how can I detect when website, which uses AJAX requests is ready (e.g. when a website which is fetching some search results by using AJAX finished its work) ?

Comment: I guess you will have to implement some kind of queue and keep track of when everything in the queue is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a trick i developed my self.

1-in your html page make a div and set its text to "false".

2-in you server side put a javascript at the end of your returning code. for example your site returns following text upon an ajax call.

a
b
c
d
e

so after this text put a javascript code that will change the text of div from "false" to "true"

so what will happen is that once you receive all the data from ajax call you will also receive the javascript code and that code will run and set the value of div.

so in your page once all data is received you will see the indicator div. and you will know that you have received all data. you can also run functions in similar way upon completion of data.

Comment: this is not my site: I cannot change the page source